# how can I make the index of a matrix increment in this function in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, auto-increment

I have a matlab function to detect the index array that has data below threshold

the result index_list will be in n x 2 matrix where
index_list(i,1) = row
index_list(i,2) = column

that have element array < threshold

Since I don't know how many result would be in index_list

```
function [index_list] = pickindex(Array,Threshold)
index = 1;
for i= 1:size(Array,1)
    for j = 1:size(Array,2)
        if(Array(i,j) <= Threshold)
            index_list(index,1)=i;
            index_list(index,2)=j;
            index = index +1;
        end
    end
end
```

This code is working but is there any other suggestion to improve the code?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about working code and so belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like the same thing as:

```
[r, c] = find(Array <= Threshold);
index_list = [r, c];
```

Comment: yeah I just realized that thank you